# popBackStack() and pass argument in Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to back to the previous fragment when clicking to row in the RecyclerView. So how can I call that function in my adapter?

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CountryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String country = countries.get(position);
        holder.tvCountrySelection.setText(country);
        holder.tvCountrySelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.tvCountrySelection.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_tick_17, 0);
                //I want to run popBackStack() here and send String country to previous fragment.
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can checkout this : 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

Or this : 
http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Answer (score 2):

- pass activity context through your adaptor constructor

  from fragment

  ```
     new YourAdaptor(getActivity())
  ```

  from activity

  ```
    new YourAdaptor(this)
  ```
- handle context in adaptor class

  ```
    globalinstance = passedContext;
  ```
- using that context you can pop back fragment on your click event like

  ```
    ((YourActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
  ```

depending on your needs you can use `popBackStack()` or `popBackStackImmediate()`.